# Managing google chrome's bookmarks remotely?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I use Chrome on my home computers but use Firefox at work. Is it possible, via either a remote site or FF plugin, to manage (add, edit, remove, etc) my synced chrome bookmarks without having to be in the Chrome browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do that (that I know of) is to install the [Xmarks plugin](http://www.xmarks.com/) it syncs bookmarks (and a lot more if you want) across IE, Firefox, Chrome & Safari.

Comment: Does this work with the built-in bookmark synching functionality?

Comment: @Ryan - I use it instead of the built in bookmark syncing. There might possibly be conflicts if you used both.

Comment: Xmarks is about to shutdown right ?

Comment: @Sathya - Doesn't seem like it any more. http://blog.xmarks.com/

Comment: @Nifle - Interesting turnaround. Thanks.

Comment: Great news about Xmarks! It rocks. I'd pay $20 / year for it if I could.